# Angular Routing bind parameter substitution

Tags: angular

I'm using router.navigate like so:

```
this.router.navigate([link, params])
```

where link is the url and params is an object that contains the key/values of the parameters.  This works however it's not exactly what I want to do.

I am working with a primeNG datatable which is in a custom component.  I want to just give it a linkMap so that I can link specific columns in the table using a parameterized URL template like so:

id = /detail/:id

in my table I will check the map to see if the particular column needs to be linked (i.e. "id") then grab the URL.  What I want to do then is to substitute :id for the data that is in context for that row, such as /detail/5 etc.  This is simple enough but what I am currently getting is:

/detail:id;id=5

How do I substitute the :id itself to the value 5?  I can do it via regexp but would rather use Angular built-in functionality if it exists.

To Clarify: I have a key/value map and a string with **named** parameters, I need to do an in place substitution:

/detail/:id/:code/:subcode/:id/:id, {id: 5, code: 'PRG', subcode: 'AB'} should result in the URL /detail/5/PRG/AB/5/5

I can't supply the arguments in the required order i.e. [5, 'PRG', 'AB', 5, 5] because that would require me to figure out the order of the parameters.  I need Angular to do this for me.

Answer (score 0):

By looking at your current URL output, it seems like you're creating URL like `router.navigate(['/details/:id', {id: 5}])` which generates undesired URL `/details/:id;id=5`. Rather it should be

```
router.navigate(['/details', {id: 5}]);
//will for '/details/5'
```

In case of multiple parameter, it will look like

```
router.navigate(['/details', {id: 5, testId: 1}]);
//will for '/details/5/1'
```

Comment: I can't get this to work:

this.router.navigate['/details/:id', 5] results in: /details/:id/5, i.e. it simply concatenates the value to the URL which per the docs is the expected behavior, it does not do a substitution.  Also, I cannot supply the parameters in the exact order because that is not know beforehand, for instance the URL template can be:

/detail/:id/:code/:subcode or /detail/:code/:id/:subcode etc. whatever is defined should be substituted based on the row data that is available.  It needs to be totally generic so that any permutation and combination works.

Comment: @SBKDeveloper can you please consider the updated answer. Sorry last solution was incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using TypeScript don't perform any string manipulation.  Use template literals via back-ticks to add the value to your route:

```
this.router.navigate([`/details/${id}`, params]);
```

Comment: I can't do this because I don't have the value of id at the time the URL template is defined.  This is defined by the consumer of the component, they can set it to anything they want.

Comment: I think this would be easier to answer if you provided more of a code example.  It is really easy to set up a project using https://stackblitz.com.  One click and you have an Angular project just need to add relevant code then post the example link.